# The use of the grammar structure "if" + "would" in context

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, modal-verbs, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

I stumbled upon it in this [video](https://youtu.be/BqP4_4kr7-0). It is at 1 hour 21 minute and 42 second.

> If the Israelis **would** ever once just say we got screwed in 1948, and we are sorry it happened, we would be willing to make peace.

I think it is quite clear that the sentence is conditional, thus it is not correct to use *would* in the if clause. Did the lecturer say that by mistake? Or is that some kind of grammar I am not aware of? And by the way, what does *get screwed* mean there?

Comment: This is a question of dialect. American English uses this construction often; British English hardly ever. (In Britain we would say "If the Israelis ever once just said...") So it is correct English.

Comment: @TonyK I believe you have mistaken a wholly licit and common construction for a widely condemned one. The two are unrelated and so should not be tarred with the same brush. The one considered sub- or non-standard runs along the lines of *If it ?would have rained, we would have been happier*. The one that's just fine is the backshifted version of *If you will please leash your dogs, we can let the cats in* > *If you would please leash your dogs, we can/could let the cats in,* where the backshifting softens the request for politeness' sake, **not** for an irrealis protasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, **this** particular “double-*would*” scenario is perfectly fine (unlike most of them).

That’s because the first *would* in your sentence is the one that means to be willing or wanting to do something. It’s about willingness, volition.

Read it this way:

> If only the Israelis had ever once been willing to just say that we got screwed in 1948 and that they're sorry it happened, we would be willing to make peace.

The reason speakers of foreign languages are told they should “never” use *will* or *would* in the *if* part of a conditional is not because this is true, but because it stops them from making common blunders that native speakers simply do not say.

For example, these are all wrong but are commonly heard from learners trying to compose valid English conditional constructions:

1. If it *will rain, we will stay home.
2. It if *would rain, we would stay home.
3. If it *would have rained, we would have stayed home.

It is easy to correct those to make them grammatical:

4. If it rains, we will stay home.
5. It if rained, we would stay home.
6. If it had rained, we would have stayed home.

However, your example sentence did not use *would* in the *if* part incorrectly. That’s because this is the version of that verb which means *to want to* or *to be willing to*. It is about willingness, not about probability. Given that only animate subjects can be willing, it is impossible to use this form in the *if it rains* examples given above.

However, it is perfectly normal to use *if you will* or *if you would* in de-facto requests like these:

7. If you **will** please give me your name, we **can** get started here.
8. If you **would** please give me your name, we **can** get started here.

As you see, these are more like polite requests than they are expressions of a non-real scenario in the *if* part. The reason *would* happens in the second version is because we routinely backshift to make a request more polite. Therefore the second of these is more polite than the first:

9. **Will** you please give me your name so we can get started here?
10. **Would** you please give me your name so we can get started here?

There are other, rarer occasions to use *would* in conjunction with *if*. One of those is when it’s an *if only*:

11. If only it would rain!
12. If only it were so!

Those two are cases for which some languages use an dedicated optative mood to express, but English doesn’t have that. But English does use the same forms with *wish* that it uses with *if only*:

13. I wish it would rain.
14. I wish it were so.

This is not intended to be an exclusive set of all possible legal *if* + *will/would* combinations that natives use but learners are seldom taught. There are more possibilities that are legal. Native speakers create far more forms of conditionals, all grammatical, than learners are ever taught.

The directive “never” to use *will* or *would* in a conditional is a simplified version of reality that attempts to block common errors. No native speaker is ever told this.

For your other question, *to be/get screwed* means to be cheated or to be unfairly made to suffer some loss or figurative injury at someone else's hand, and there's nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: Could you tell me what "get screwed" mean?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Sure thing, *to be/get screwed* means to be cheated or to be unfairly made to suffer some loss or figurative injury at someone else's hand.